# Are "ŝati" and "plaĉi al" interchangeable?

Tags: word-usage

Since there are two words that express liking something, *ŝati* and *plaĉi al*, are they interchangeable, or are there certain contexts that it would be better to use *ŝati* and other contexts that it would be more appropriate to use *plaĉi al*?

(Ex: *mi ŝatas kokaĵon* versus *kokaĵo plaĉas al mi*)

Comment: En via ekzemplo „kokaĵo plaĉas al mi” „kokaĵo” estas la subjekto de la frazo, kaj do ne povas havi -n. Bonvolu korekti. Dankon!

Comment: Ho! Mi ne rimarkis ke mi faris tion! Dankon!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mi kredas, ke efektive oni ĉiam povas uzi la du formojn:

- Vojaĝoj plaĉas al mi. Mi ŝatas vojaĝojn.
- Al kiu plaĉas milito? Kiu ŝatas militon?
- Al Nancy plaĉas muziko. Nancy ŝatas muzikon.
- Vi plaĉas al mi. Mi ŝatas vin.
- Naĝi plaĉas al mi. Mi ŝatas naĝi.

Tamen, se en la frazo kun *plaĉi* mankas la parto *al*, oni devas *inventi* novan subjekton en la frazo kun *ŝati*, ekzemple:

- Iam plaĉas nur vagadi sencele. Iam **oni** ŝatas nur vagadi sencele.
- Vizito al Berlino ĉiam plaĉas. **Mi** ĉiam ŝatas viziti Berlinon.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on who you ask. In the first decades of Esperanto, the word "ŝati" did not have the current meaning, but had the meaning that is nowadays expressed with "aprezi".

My impression is that *mi ŝatas kokaĵon* and *kokaĵo plaĉas al mi* used to be somewhat more distinct in meaning than they are today. Most speakers today would take these two sentences as meaning basically the same thing.

As a counter example, consider this Zamenhofian example taken from PIV:

- nobla viro devas dece ŝati la vorton de virino

This seems to mean something different than this:

- al nobla viro devas dece plaĉi la vorto de virino

In the first one, the noble man is being asked to place a high value on the word of the woman. In the second, we're simply saying that a woman's words should be pleasing to him.

Comment: In the first decades of Esperanto, the word "ŝati" did not have the current meaning, but had the meaning that is nowadays expressed with "aprezi", i.e. "to appreciate / to esteem". But it's current meaning is the same as that of "plaĉi", the only difference being the grammatically different behaviour of the two words.

Comment: Thanks. I've been looking for a reference for that but haven't found one yet. My thought is that a complete answer to this question should include the information that they were not originally synonyms (or "functional synonyms" if you prefer.)

Comment: I have noticed a tendency among Romance language speakers to prefer _plaĉi_.